# What does $#array mean in Perl?

Tags: perl

I'm looking at the following code snippet:

```
my @ret = <someMethod>
return (undef) if( $DB_ERROR );
return (undef) unless ($#ret >= 0);
```

Does `$#` just give you a count of elements in a array?

Comment: I changed $# to $#array in the title. You should realize that $# by itself is a is a magical variable (though I think it got removed in Perl 5.10)

Comment: Also, I'd like to point out you have a potential bug in your script. You should not return (undef), but simply say return. In list context, your function will evaluate as true!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`$#arrayname` gives you the index of the last element, so if array `@ret` has 2 elements then `$#ret` is 1.

And, as noted by Barry Brown, an empty array gives -1.

To get the length you can use the array in scalar context:

```
print scalar @ret;
```

Comment: Also, if @ret has nothing in it, $#ret will return -1.

Answer (score 26):

edg is correct, but the original code is unnecessarily obtuse.  In most cases, `$#foo` is a red flag that the code could be written more simply using `scalar @foo`.

```
return (undef) unless ($#ret >= 0);
```

`unless foo >= bar` is difficult to puzzle out.  First, turn it into a positive statement.

```
return (undef) if ($#ret < 0);
```

When is $#ret < 0?  When it's -1.  A $#ret of -1 is an array of length 0.  So the above can be written much more simply as...

```
return (undef) if scalar @ret <= 0;
```

But you can't have a negative length array, so...

```
return (undef) if scalar @ret == 0;
```

And == is in scalar context, so that "scalar" is redundant...

```
return (undef) if @ret == 0;
```

But that's just a wordy way of saying "if `@ret` is false".

```
return (undef) if !@ret;
```

Which I think for simple statement modifiers is better expressed with unless.

```
return (undef) unless @ret;
```

Isn't that easier to follow?

As a final side-note, `return undef` is discouraged because it does the wrong thing in list context.  You get back a list containing one undef element, which is true.  Instead, just use a blank return which returns undef in scalar context and an empty list in list context.

```
return unless @ret;
```

Comment: And one place where $#foo isn't a red flag would be in an array slice...  my @five_to_end = @foo[ 5 .. $#foo ];

Comment: Re: `return undef` being discouraged.  In some cases, you do want to return an explicit `undef` even in list context.  It depends on how the function is usually used.  It's not that you shouldn't use `return undef`, it's just that you shouldn't use it without thinking "why am I using `return undef` here?"  If you have a good answer, then go ahead and do it.

Comment: > $#foo is a red flag that the code
No, it's not.  Both serve different purposes.  `@foo` is a count of elements, and `$#foo` is the last index.  If you're running through a for-index loop, you want to use `$#foo`.  Same with the array slice @draegtun mentioned.  For the use case the OP presented, `@foo` is more accurate, since the statements are just checking for a non-zero count of elements.

Comment: @BrendanByrd Yes, they do serve different purposes. `$#foo` has its uses, but *in most cases* they indicate the code could be simpler. Full 3-part for loops are themselves a red flag, as is iterating by index. `for my $idx (0..$#foo)` has its uses, but they can often be better written as `for my $thing (@foo)`.

Comment: @BrendanByrd To clarify, a red flag indicates something which requires increased scrutiny; not something which is prohibited. I have found it very common for novices (and many tutorials) to use `$#foo` when they should be using `@foo`.

Answer (score 6):

Be aware that the $#array expression will return -1 when array has zero elements.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize everyone else, that code is much more legible if written like this:

```
my @ret = someMethod();
return if $DB_ERROR;
return unless @ret;
```

Comment: That's semantically different. `return;` and `return undef;` behave differently in list context (returning an empty list and returning a one-element list containing `undef`, respectively).