# Find size of an array in Perl

Tags: perl

I seem to have come across several different ways to find the size of an array. What is the difference between these three methods?

```
my @arr = (2);
print scalar @arr; # First way to print array size

print $#arr; # Second way to print array size

my $arrSize = @arr;
print $arrSize; # Third way to print array size
```

Comment: other ways: `print 0+@arr`, `print "".@arr`, `print ~~@arr`

Comment: @mob, hum, one might want to avoid `"".@arr` as `"@arr"` does something quite different.

Comment: The "second way" is NOT a way to print the array size...

Comment: in scalar context ;@arr returns table size. $x=@arr is scalar context. $#arr returns last index of array. indexing starting at 0, then is true equation $#arr+1 == @arr . If you write some element out of order, for example $arr[100]='any', then table is automatically increased to max index 100, and (including index 0) to 101 elements.

Comment: Candidates: *[What does $#array mean in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241388/)* (2008-10-27)

Answer (score 265, accepted):

The first and third ways are the same: they evaluate an array in scalar context. I would consider this to be the standard way to get an array's size.

The second way actually returns the last index of the array, which is not (usually) the same as the array size.

Comment: What's the difference between the last index and the array size? Is the index not sequential from 0 to the array size?

Comment: The size of (1,2,3) is 3, and the indexes are (by default) 0, 1 and 2. So, $#arr will be 2 in this case, not 3.

Comment: The predefined variable `$[` specifies "The index of the first element in an array, and of the first character in a substring" (`perldoc perlvar`).  It's set to 0 by default, and setting it to anything other than 0 is highly discouraged.

Comment: @Keith Thompson, `$[` is discouraged (and has been for a decade). `$[` is deprecated. Using `$[` issues a deprecation warning even when one doesn't turn on warnings. Assigning anything but zero to `$[` will be an error in 5.16. Can we stop mentioning `$[` already?

Comment: @ikegami: Sure, we can stop mentioning `$[` as soon as everyone in the world stops using versions of Perl older than 5.16.  8-)}

Comment: @Keith Thompson, Older than 5.14, actually. But like I said, it's been discouraged and deprecated for far longer than that, and someone using `$[` would know of its effects.

Comment: @ikegami: Yes, but someone trying to understand the difference between `scalar @arr` and `$#arr` should *still* understand the possible effects of `$[`, rare though they are.

Comment: @Keith Tompson, I beg to differ. Someone who doesn't use `$[` doesn't need to know about its effects. And as I already said, the person using `$[` --if the person even exists-- already knows its effects. There's no point in going through all this for the benefit of the non-existent person that uses `$[` without knowing what it is.

Answer (score 49):

First, the second (`$#array`) is not equivalent to the other two. `$#array` returns the last index of the array, which is one less than the size of the array.

The other two (`scalar @arr` and `$arrSize = @arr`) are virtually the same. You are simply using two different means to create scalar context. It comes down to a question of readability.

I personally prefer the following:

```
say 0+@array;          # Represent @array as a number
```

I find it clearer than

```
say scalar(@array);    # Represent @array as a scalar
```

and

```
my $size = @array;
say $size;
```

The latter looks quite clear alone like this, but I find that the extra line takes away from clarity when part of other code. It's useful for teaching what `@array` does in scalar context, and maybe if you want to use `$size` more than once.

Comment: Personally I prefer the version that uses the "scalar" keyword, because it's quite explicit that it's forcing a scalar context. `my $size=@array` looks like it might be a mistake where the wrong sigil was used.

Comment: That's a really bad idea. People who use `scalar` for no reason learn the wrong lesson. They start getting into their heads that operators return lists that can be coerced into scalars. Seen it dozens of times.

Comment: Why is this "no reason"? You are using `scalar` because you are coercing the list to a scalar context. That is the right reason to use it. Your example does exactly the same thing, but relies on what Perl does when you evaluate a list variable in an implicitly scalar context. Thus, your example requires the reader to know about Perl's implicit behavior in that context. You're just adding one more layer of implicit behavior to the expression, and Perl already has too much implicit behavior that you have to reason through to decipher a program.

Comment: @Nate C-K, Re "Why is this "no reason"? You are using `scalar` because you are coercing the list to a scalar context", You've proving my point about learning the wrong lesson. This is completely false. No list is ever coerced by `scalar`. (If it did, `scalar(@array)` and `scalar(@array[0..$#array])` would return the same thing.) `scalar(@array)` tells `@array` to return a scalar, which you already told it to do with `my $size=`.

Comment: The original example wasn't `my $size = scalar(@array);`, it was `say scalar(@array);`. I see what you mean about the assignment, that in that context it is redundant, although as I pointed out before it clarifies your intent (since mixing up sigils is an extremely common mistake in Perl).

Comment: @Nate C-K, Re "The original example wasn't `my $size = scalar(@array);`", So? I never said there was no reason for `scalar` in the original. It was in reply to you saying `my $size=@array;` shouldn't be used.

Comment: @Nate C-K, Re "it clarifies your intent", How so? Does anything think you can assign something other than a scalar to a scalar? No, it superfluous and harmful.

Comment: As I said (twice), because it's possible to mix up the sigils. Programmers write `my $x = @y` when they meant `my @x = @y` or `my $x = $y`. This happens all the time in Perl, whether it's due to confusion or just a simple typo.

Comment: @Nate C-K, Re "it's possible to mix up the sigils", 1) I know you said that, but it doesn't answer my question. I asked how does `scalar($x)` clarify intent? 2) Re "Programmers write `my $x = @y` when they meant `my @x = @y` or `my $x = $y`", No they don't. The program wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes... that's why it's a bug.

Comment: @Nate C-K, It won't even compile, so the only reader is the programmer who just wrote the code. You're saying he needs to tell himself what he means as he's writing the code? nah. No reason to do that. How about you have the programmer remember to use a scalar rather than remember to use `scalar`.

Comment: Believe it or not, developers have to debug code written by other developers. And developers have to debug code that they wrote three years ago.

Comment: @Nate C-K, I'm not too worried about the programmer's ability to debug a program noone ever ran.

Answer (score 32):

This gets the size by forcing the array into a scalar context, in which it is evaluated as its size:

```
print scalar @arr;
```

This is another way of forcing the array into a scalar context, since it's being assigned to a scalar variable:

```
my $arrSize = @arr;
```

This gets the index of the last element in the array, so it's actually the size minus 1 (assuming indexes start at 0, which is adjustable in Perl although doing so is usually a bad idea):

```
print $#arr;
```

This last one isn't really good to use for getting the array size. It would be useful if you just want to get the last element of the array:

```
my $lastElement = $arr[$#arr];
```

Also, as you can see here on Stack Overflow, this construct isn't handled correctly by most syntax highlighters...

Comment: A sidenote: just use `$arr[-1]` to get the last element. And `$arr[-2]` to get the penultimate one, and so on.

Comment: @tuomassalo: I agree  that your suggestion is a better approach. In retrospect, `$#arr` isn't a very useful feature, and it's no accident that other languages don't have it.

Answer (score 8):

To use the second way, add 1:

```
print $#arr + 1; # Second way to print array size
```

Comment: `for [0..$#array] { print $array[$_ ] }`  works really well though if the purpose of getting the number of elements is to iterate through array. The advantage being that you get the element as well as a counter that are aligned.

Answer (score 6):

All three give the same result if we modify the second one a bit:

```
my @arr = (2, 4, 8, 10);

print "First result:\n";
print scalar @arr; 

print "\n\nSecond result:\n";
print $#arr + 1; # Shift numeration with +1 as it shows last index that starts with 0.

print "\n\nThird result:\n";
my $arrSize = @arr;
print $arrSize;
```

Comment: Is this anything different from what has already been mentioned in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7407036/2235132) answer and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18797985/2235132) one?

Answer (score 5):

Example:

```
my @a = (undef, undef);
my $size = @a;

warn "Size: " . $#a;   # Size: 1. It's not the size
warn "Size: " . $size; # Size: 2
```

Answer (score 3):

The [“Perl variable types” section](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Perl-variable-types) of the [perlintro documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html) contains

> The special variable `$#array` tells you the index of the last element of an array:
>
> ```
> print $mixed[$#mixed];       # last element, prints 1.23
> ```
>
> You might be tempted to use `$#array + 1` to tell you how many items there are in an array. Don’t bother. As it happens, using `@array` where Perl expects to find a scalar value (“in scalar context”) will give you the number of elements in the array:
>
> ```
> if (@animals < 5) { ... }
> ```

The [perldata documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) also covers this in the [“Scalar values” section](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-values).

> If you evaluate an array in scalar context, it returns the length of the array. (Note that this is not true of lists, which return the last value, like the C comma operator, nor of built-in functions, which return whatever they feel like returning.) The following is always true:
>
> ```
> scalar(@whatever) == $#whatever + 1;
> ```
>
> Some programmers choose to use an explicit conversion so as to leave nothing to doubt:
>
> ```
> $element_count = scalar(@whatever);
> ```

Earlier in the same section documents how to obtain the index of the last element of an array.

> The length of an array is a scalar value. You may find the length of array `@days` by evaluating `$#days`, as in `csh`. However, this isn’t the length of the array; it’s the subscript of the last element, which is a different value since there is ordinarily a 0th element.

Answer (score 3):

From perldoc [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html), which should be safe to quote:

> The following is always true:
>
> ```
> scalar(@whatever) == $#whatever + 1;
> ```

Just so long as you don't $#whatever++ and mysteriously increase the size or your array.

> The array indices start with 0.

and

> You can truncate an array down to nothing by assigning the null list () to it. The following are equivalent:
>
> ```
>     @whatever = ();
>     $#whatever = -1;
> ```

Which brings me to what I was looking for which is how to detect the array is empty. I found it if $#empty == -1;

Answer (score 3):

There are various ways to print size of an array. Here are the meanings of all:

Let’s say our array is `my @arr = (3,4);`

#### Method 1: scalar

This is the right way to get the size of arrays.

```
print scalar @arr;  # Prints size, here 2
```

#### Method 2: Index number

`$#arr` gives the last index of an array. So if array is of size 10 then its last index would be 9.

```
print $#arr;     # Prints 1, as last index is 1
print $#arr + 1; # Adds 1 to the last index to get the array size
```

We are adding 1 here, considering the array as **0-indexed**. But, if it's not zero-based then, **this logic will fail**.

```
perl -le 'local $[ = 4; my @arr = (3, 4); print $#arr + 1;'   # prints 6
```

The above example prints 6, because we have set its initial index to 4. Now the index would be 5 and 6, with elements 3 and 4 respectively.

#### Method 3:

When an array is used in a scalar context, then it returns the size of the array

```
my $size = @arr;
print $size;   # Prints size, here 2
```

Actually, method 3 and method 1 are same.

Answer (score 1):

Use `int(@array)` as it threats the argument as scalar.

Answer (score 0):

To find the size of an array use the `scalar` keyword:

```
print scalar @array;
```

To find out the last index of an array there is `$#` (Perl default variable). It gives the last index of an array. As an array starts from 0, we get the size of array by adding one to `$#`:

```
print "$#array+1";
```

Example:

```
my @a = qw(1 3 5);
print scalar @a, "\n";
print $#a+1, "\n";
```

Output:

```
3

3
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"Perl default variable"*?

Answer (score 0):

As numerous answers pointed out, the first and third way are the correct methods to get the array size, and the second way is not.

Here I expand on these answers with some usage examples.

`@array_name` evaluates to the length of the array = the size of the array = the number of elements in the array, **when used in a scalar context**.

Below are some examples of a scalar context, such as `@array_name` by itself inside `if` or `unless`, of in arithmetic comparisons such as `==` or `!=`.

All of these examples will work if you change `@array_name` to `scalar(@array_name)`. This would make the code more explicit, but also longer and slightly less readable. Therefore, more idiomatic usage omitting `scalar()` is preferred here.

```
my @a = (undef, q{}, 0, 1);

# All of these test whether 'array' has four elements:
print q{array has four elements} if @a == 4;
print q{array has four elements} unless @a != 4;
@a == 4 and print q{array has four elements};
!(@a != 4) and print q{array has four elements};

# All of the above print:
# array has four elements

# All of these test whether array is not empty:
print q{array is not empty} if @a;
print q{array is not empty} unless !@a;
@a and print q{array is not empty};
!(!@a) and print q{array is not empty};

# All of the above print:
# array is not empty
```