# How should I use the "my" keyword in Perl?

Tags: perl, scope, declaration

I keep seeing the `my` keyword in front of variable names in example Perl scripts online, but I have no idea what it means. I tried reading the manual pages and other sites online, but I'm having difficulty discerning what it is for, given the difference between how I see it used and the manual.

For example, it is used to get the length of the array in this post:
[Find size of an array in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406807/find-size-of-array-in-perl)

But the manual says:

> A `my` declares the listed variables to be local (lexically) to the
> enclosing block, file, or eval. If more than one value is listed, the
> list must be placed in parentheses.

What does it do and how is it used?

Comment: Re "its used to get the length of the array in this post", Not at all. `my` did not factor into it in the least. It's the scalar assignment operator (`=`) that enforced the scalar context on `@arr`.

Comment: If it's not really "yours", you should not use it.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

`my` restricts the [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29) of a variable. The scope of a variable is where it can be seen. Reducing a variable's scope to where the variable is needed is a fundamental aspect of good programming. It makes the code more readable and less error-prone, and results in a slew of derived benefits.

If you don't declare a variable using `my`, a global variable will be created instead. This is to be avoided. Using `use strict;` tells Perl you want to be prevented from implicitly creating global variables, which is why you should always use `use strict;` (and `use warnings;`) in your programs.

---

Related reading: [Why use `use strict;` and `use warnings;`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8024241/589924)

Comment: For people coming here from JS: It's essentially like `var` and `let` in JavaScript. Without `'use strict';` JS will let you declare new global variables without either keyword, which isn't considered the best of practices.

Comment: @Electric Coffee, In JS terms, the question would be "What does `let` and `var` do and how should they be used?" And yes, the answer would be roughly the same. (JS's `let` vars are a lot like Perl's `my` vars, except that `let` vars can't be captured.)

Comment: I just meant that if people came to Perl from JS, it would be an easy way to explain the same concept

Comment: @ElectricCoffee 1) A programmer that understands scoping doesn't need to have it explained to them again after switching languages. 2) Not sure that you actually did explain scoping, in terms a JS programmer would understand or otherwise. Maybe you were trying to explain `use strict;`? But that wasn't the question, and `use strict;` does more than that. Or maybe you meant to communicate that `my` limits the scope of vars kinda like `let` and `var` do, but that's pretty much the first sentence of the answer. 3) If you wish to answer a question differently, that's what Answers are for.

Answer (score 30):

Quick summary: `my` creates a new variable, `local` temporarily amends the value of a variable

In the example below, $::a refers to $a in the 'global' namespace.

```
$a = 3.14159;
{
  my $a = 3;
  print "In block, \$a = $a\n";
  print "In block, \$::a = $::a\n";
}
print "Outside block, \$a = $a\n";
print "Outside block, \$::a = $::a\n";

# This outputs
In block, $a = 3
In block, $::a = 3.14159
Outside block, $a = 3.14159
Outside block, $::a = 3.14159
```

ie, `local` temporarily changes the value of the variable, but only within the scope it exists in.

Source: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=94007

**Update**

About difference between `our` and `my` please see

- [What is the difference between my and our in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845060/what-is-the-difference-between-my-and-our-in-perl)

(Thanks to *ThisSuitIsBlackNot*).

Comment: I think this answer needs some adjusting. You have a code example demonstrating the use of `my`, but then follow that up with a sentence talking about `local` as if you had just demonstrated `local`'s use, despite that `local` is not demonstrated anywhere in this answer. I think you kind of misquoted the source on PerlMonks, which has two code examples. The sentence about `local` was describing the other one, not the one you transcribed here.

Comment: Why even mention `local` when you don't use it in the code example?

Comment: @Greenonline: With this logic, if you have no code example at all, you shouldn't mention anything?

Comment: Well yes. As mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889609/how-should-i-use-the-my-keyword-in-perl/20889656?noredirect=1#comment75064909_20889656), the code example that you give doesn't show the use of `local`. However, you then explain the scope of `local`, but it hasn't been demonstrated. The problem is that you've copied the wrong code snippet from the perlmonks page. It's rather misleading.

Comment: @IgorChubin To phrase what others have said another way, what you have written is analogous to "Oranges are fruits, cabbages are vegetables, `example of uses for oranges`, i.e. this example (which doesn't mention cabbages) demonstrates something about cabbages". I.e. you have an example that demonstrates `my` and then follow it up by talking as if you had demonstrated what `local` does, making the information about `local` seem like an irrelevant non sequitur. The article you linked to demonstrates _both_ in order to contrast their behaviours. Without _both_ examples, your answer is confusing.

Answer (score 6):

[Private Variables via my()](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my%28%29) is the primary documentation for `my`.

In the array size example you mention, it's not used to find the size of the array.  It's used to create a new variable to hold the size of the array.