# PERL PROBLmy $str1 = 0 unless defined $str1;

Tags: perl

I am a beginner in perl programming and when i try this code with use strict and use warnings  it throws an error saying "Global symbol $str1 requires explicit package name".Do we need to use any other packages to use unless keyword? ..please help

Comment: It is from [`use strict;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889609/how-should-i-use-the-my-keyword-in-perl) You should declare the variable using [`my`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html). `my $str1 = 0;`. [Why use strict and warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings/8024241)

Comment: The `my $str1` is what is checked at compile time, however `$str1` in the same statement (with `defined`) is also checked, and had not been declared yet.  You can't declare it (`my $s`) and have it be used as already declared (`defined $s`) in the same statement.  Declare first.  Having said that, I find this to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, you need to declare $str1 explicitly

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $str1;
$str1 = 0 unless defined $str1;
```

Comment: Of course, that's equivalent to `my $str1 = 0;`