# perl string eval misunderstood

Tags: perl, eval

I'm trying to return a reference to a hash from a string value but the results depends on the order of when the hash and sub are defined.

Snippet 1:

```perl
my $uid = { '199' => 'Twister', '396' => 'Khorus', '450' => 'Ling', '555' => 'Sage' };
sub href { eval "\$$_[0]" }
print Dumper href('uid');
```

Output of snippet 1:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '199' => 'Twister',
          '396' => 'Khorus',
          '450' => 'Ling',
          '555' => 'Sage'
        };
```

Snippet 2:

```perl
sub href { eval "\$$_[0]" }
my $uid = { '199' => 'Twister', '396' => 'Khorus', '450' => 'Ling', '555' => 'Sage' };
print Dumper href('uid');
```

Output of snippet 2:

```
$VAR1 = undef;
```

It shouldn't matter if the sub is defined before or after the hash but it does. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole [point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20890822/589924) of using `my` to is limit the scope (visibility) of variables. `my` variables are scoped from the statement after which they are created to the end of the innermost block in which they are located, which means they are only visible to that code. (The file itself acts as a block.)

```
# This code can't see $x.
my $x;
# This code can see $x.

{
   # This code can't see $y.
   my $y;
   # This code can see $y.
}
# This code can't see $y.
```

To be clear, this is strictly based on where the code is located in the source; it's not based on when code is executed.

As such, `my $uid` needs to be found before the sub's declaration in order for the sub to see the variable. You can always set its value later, however.

---

That said, what you are doing is horrible! You are intentionally doing the very thing we force ourselves to not do by using `use strict;` in every program! See [Why it's stupid to `use a variable as a variable name'](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) and [A More Direct Explanation of the Problem](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname2.html).

Instead, replace

```
 my $uid;

 sub href { eval "\$$_[0]" }

 $uid = { '199' => 'Twister', '396' => 'Khorus', '450' => 'Ling', '555' => 'Sage' };
```

with

```
 my %data;

 sub href { $data{$_[0]} }

 $data{uid} = { '199' => 'Twister', '396' => 'Khorus', '450' => 'Ling', '555' => 'Sage' };
```

Comment: I was using your suggestion in my code. I guess this means that if a subroutine tries to use a variable outside of it's scope, even with an eval, it needs to be declared before the sub definition.

Comment: A sub can never use a variable outside of its scope (except indirectly e.g. using a reference). Outside of its scope literally means it can't see it.