# How can I use perl to delete files matching a regex

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

Due to a `Makefile` mistake, I have some fake files in my git repo...

```bash
$ ls
=0.1.1                  =4.8.0                  LICENSE
=0.5.3                  =5.2.0                  Makefile
=0.6.1                  =7.1.0                  pyproject.toml
=0.6.1,                 all_commands.txt        README_git_workflow.md
=0.8.1                  CHANGES.md              README.md
=1.2.0                  ciscoconfparse/         requirements.txt
=1.7.0                  configs/                sphinx-doc/
=2.0                    CONTRIBUTING.md         tests/
=2.2.0                  deploy_docs.py          tutorial/
=22.2.0                 dev_tools/              utils/
=22.8.0                 do.py
=2.7.0                  examples/
$
```

I tried this, but it seems that there may be some *more efficient means to accomplish this task*...

```perl
# glob "*" will list all files globbed against "*"
foreach my $filename (grep { /\W\d+\.\d+/ } glob "*") {
    my $cmd1 = "rm $filename";
    `$cmd1`;
}
```

#### Question:

- I want a remove command that matches against a pcre.
- *What is a more efficient `perl` solution to delete the files matching this perl regex: `/\W\d+\.\d+/` (example filename: '=0.1.1')*?

Comment: Is that `=` by any chance an indicator of the file-type in your `ls`, which may have been aliased with `-F`? (Ir is it really a literal character?)  I added this to my answer

Comment: You could try any of `rm =*`, `rm =[0,1,2,22,33,4,5,7]*`, `find . -type f -name '=*' -exec rm {} \;` in shell.

Comment: Please see [Linux / Unix: Find And Remove Files With One Command On Fly](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-how-to-find-and-remove-files/)

Comment: @PolarBear if we’re going to suggest non-perl alternative solutions, `fd` is the best I’ve found…. https://github.com/sharkdp/fd

Comment: Is `fd` a part of Linux/Unix OS? Or you have to compile it from source code?

Comment: @PolarBear, you don't have to compile `fd`; it's available in several [linux distros via package manager](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd#installation), you can use one of the [official github release binaries](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd/releases), or use [`rustc / cargo`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/what-is-rustc.html) to compile `fd` from source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fetch a wider set of files and then filter through whatever you want

```
my @files_to_del = grep { /^\W[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/ and not -d } glob "$dir/*";
```

I added an anchor (`^`) so that the regex can only match a string that *begins* with that pattern, otherwise this can blow away files other than intended. Reconsider what exactly you need.

Altogether perhaps (or see a one-liner below <sup>†</sup>)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use File::Glob ':bsd_glob';  # for better glob()
use Cwd qw(cwd);             # current-working-directory

my $dir = shift // cwd;      # cwd by default, or from input 

my $re = qr/^\W[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/;  

my @files_to_del = grep { /$re/ and not -d } glob "$dir/*"; 

say for @files_to_del;  # please inspect first

#unlink or warn "Can't unlink $_: $!" for @files_to_del;
```

where that `*` in `glob` might as well have *some* pre-selection, if suitable. In particular, if the `=` is a literal character (and not an indicator printed by the shell, see footnote)<sup>‡</sup> then `glob "=*"` will fetch files starting with it, and then you can pass those through a `grep` filter.

I exclude directories, identified by `-d` [filetest](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X), since we are looking for files (and to not mix with some scary language about directories from [unlink](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink), thanks to `brian d foy` comment).

If you'd need to scan subdirectories and do the same with them, perhaps recursively -- what doesn't seem to be the case here? -- then we could employ this logic in `File::Find::find` (or `File::Find::Rule`, or yet others).

Or read the directory any other way (`opendir`+`readdir`, libraries like `Path::Tiny`), and filter.

---

<sup>†</sup> Or, a quick one-liner ... print (to inspect) what's about to get blown away

```
perl -wE'say for grep { /^\W[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/ and not -d } glob "*"'
```

and then delete 'em

```
perl -wE'unlink or warn "$_: $!" for grep /^\W[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/ && !-d, glob "*"'
```

(I switched to a more compact syntax just so. Not necessary)

If you'd like to be able to pass a directory to it  (optionally, or work in the current one) then do

```
perl -wE'$d = shift//q(.); ...'  dirpath (relative path fine. optional)
```

and then use `glob "$d/*"` in the code. This works the same way as in the script above -- [shift](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift) pulls the first element from `@ARGV`, if anything was passed to the script on the command line, or if `@ARGV` is empty it returns `undef` and then `//` ([defined-or](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Logical-Defined-Or)) operator picks up the string `q(.)`.

---

<sup>‡</sup> That leading `=` may be an "indicator" of a file type if `ls` has been aliased with `ls -F`, what can be checked by running `ls` with suppressed aliases, one way being `\ls` (or check `alias ls`).

If that is so, the `=` stands for it being a socket, what in Perl can be tested for by the `-S` filetest.

Then that `\W` in the proposed regex may need to be changed to `\W?` to allow for no non-word characters preceding a digit, along with a test for a socket. Like

```
my $re = qr/^\W? [0-9]+ \. [0-9]+/x;

my @files_to_del = grep { /$re/ and -S } glob "$dir/*";
```

Comment: Your regex is using `[0-9]+` to match integers... why not `\d+`?

Comment: @MikePennington The `\d`, as convenient as it is, matches all of Unicode "numbers."  It's I believe some 700-800 characters, "digits" of some sort or another in all kinds of writing systems. I just prefer it to be precise, `[0-9]` matches these 10 which we mean.

Comment: @MikePennington Forgot to mention, one can affect that with the `/a` modifier, so that `\d` matches only ASCII -- but then so do `\s` and `\w`, and posix character classes.  See [`/a` and `/aa` in perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#/a-(and-/aa)).  But then it all gets only more complicated, I think.  (If that _is_ an option, and one might need to adjust a bunch of regex, default modifiers for a scope can be set using [re pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/re), like `use re '/a';`)

Comment: Note that you probably want to filter out directories before unlink. The docs have some scary language about it. The problem is likely rare and improbable, but I don't rely on that.

Comment: @briandfoy Good point, thank you, better not to try to do a wrong thing.  (Also, I specifically build a list of "files.")  Fixed and added a comment on directories.

Comment: @MikePennington Updated with a minor change but a clear improvement  -- the default directory to look into should of course be the current-working-directory (I don't know why I had the script's directory as default originally?).  So that one can put it in some sort of a `~/bin` and use as a utility from anywhere.  (This need looks more like a one-off, so the one-liner may be a better fit, but still, in principle.) Thank you for all that attribution!

Answer (score 3):

Why not just:

```
$ rm =*
```

Sometimes, shell commands are the best option.

Answer (score 2):

In these cases, I use `perl` to merely filter the list of files:

```
ls | perl -ne 'print if /\A\W\d+\.\d+/a' | xargs rm
```

And, when I do that, I feel guilty for not doing something simpler with an extended pattern in `grep`:

```
ls | grep -E '^\W\d+\.\d+' | xargs rm
```

Eventually I'll run into a problem where there's a directory so I need to be more careful about the file list:

```
find . -type f  -maxdepth 1 | grep -E '^\./\W\d+\.\d+' | xargs rm
```

Or I need to allow `rm` to remove directories too should I want that:

```
ls | grep -E '^\W\d+\.\d+' | xargs rm -r
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
unlink( grep { /\W\d+\.\d+/ && !-d } glob( "*" ) );
```

This matches the filename, and excludes directories.

Comment: "_here you go_" -- agree, and I even posted that a day ago in my answer on this page (just fyi)

Comment: You should probably filter out directories from the list. The unlink docs has some notes about that.

Answer (score 0):

To delete filenames matching this: `/\W\d+\.\d+/` [pcre](https://www.pcre.org/), use the following one-liners...

1> `$fn` is a filename... I'm also removing the `my` keywords since the one-liner doesn't have to worry about [perl lexical scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20890822/667301):

```perl
perl -e 'foreach $fn (grep { /\W\d+\.\d+/ } glob "*") {$cmd1="rm $fn";`$cmd1`;}'
```

2> Or as [Andy Lester responded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73992288/667301), perhaps his answer is  as efficient as we can make it...

```perl
perl -e 'unlink(grep { /\W\d+\.\d+/ } glob "*");'
```

Comment: See also [readdir](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir), [glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob), and [unlink](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink)

Comment: Don't loop it, and use `unlink`. See my answer below.

Comment: @zdim: Well, the first bit of code has a code injection vulnerability. Not only that, since the regex is unanchored, it potentially matches more files than the original problem intended (although the question has changed significantly through this ordeal). That's why Hakon's comment is so highly upvoted.

Comment: @briandfoy OK, good points -- but people normally don't get downvoted for (the common) injection bug. Nor for the unanchored reegex, which is just what the question asks (and I copied it as well, will amend -- thanks for the reminder!). Plus there were two -1, I see one got withdrawn.  My point was, I think it's about other things and I always get itchy when content gets valued for talk outside of it